# IMEI spoofing won't fix invalid Sim Card

Tags: sim-card, imei

I recently bought a second-hand LG Pro Lite. I restored it to its factory settings. For a few days, it worked properly. A week or so later, I had no phone service. Everything else works fine.

As I boot my device, the messages displayed are as follow (one changes into the next):

1. Service Disabled
2. No Service
3. Invalid SIM Card

I have tested the SIM card in another device and it works fine. I have tested other SIM cards in my device, none work.

My best guess is that the previous owner (which can no longer be found) reported it as Stolen and provided its IMEI No., thus rendering the device useless with the carrier. (?)

I want to make the best out of a bad situation, so I rooted my device and changed my IMEI using XPOSED Framework, rebooted it and... nothing. It was properly changed, but still no service. Is there anything else I can try to use it fully?

-

System Info:

Android: **4.4.2**

Kernel Version: **3.4.67**

Phone: **LG D680** *"Pro Lite"*

Comment: What about talking to the person you bought the phone from?

Comment: As I point out, the person can no longer be found. Thus, I want to solve this through technical means.

Comment: I don't think that IMEI spoofing is the answer now, since the phone has already been blocked by the carrier. You would likely have to have it unblocked by the carrier.